# Trabajar con imagnes en Django 1.9, no se muestra mi avatar en todos mis vistas

Tags: html, django

Cuando estoy en otra vista que no sea editar usuarios o crear usuarios, no me muestra la imagen de perfil.

**Aquí cuando estoy en cualquiera de todas las vistas que tengo, no me muestra su imagen de perfil**
ejemplo: vista en productos
*código Fuente:*

```
<img src='' alt="jorgelca2"  
  class="circle responsive-img valign profile-image">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Aquí es cuando entro a editar un usuario o a registrar si me muestra la imagen de perfil**

*código fuente :*

```
<img src='/media/avatars/O3EJ9J0.jpg' alt="jorgelca2"  class="circle responsive-img valign profile-image">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi **base.html** que es el de que todas las vistas enredan el diseño. así llamo a la imagen

```
<img src='{{ object.avatar.url }}' 
    alt="{{ user.username }}"  
    class="circle responsive-img valign profile-image">
```

estoy extendiendo a user
**models.py**

```
class Usuario(AbstractUser):
telefono = models.CharField('Télefono', max_length=15)
avatar = models.ImageField('avatar para tu perfil', upload_to='avatars/', blank=True, null=True)
fondo = models.ImageField('Elige tu fondo de perfil', upload_to='fondos/', blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py del administrador

```
class CodeaAdminView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
template_name = 'codea_admin/codea_admin.html'
```

Comment: Supongo que es porque usas rutas relativas. ¿Puedes mostrar el resultado en HTML?

Comment: Cual resultado amigo ?

Comment: El código fuente de la página.

Comment: Donde mando a llamar alas imágenes ????

Comment: En tu navegador, oprime control-U, ese es el código fuente de la página.

Comment: este es el código que muestra cuando estoy editando un usuario que es solo donde me muestra el avatar. '<div class="col col s4 m4 l4">
            <img src='/media/avatars/rbm-logo-WEB-01-01.png' alt="jorgelca2"  class="circle responsive-img valign profile-image">                
              </div>'    y esto cuando estoy una vista cualquiera que no sea editar usuario, '<div class="col col s4 m4 l4">
                  <img src='' alt="jorgelca2"  class="circle responsive-img valign profile-image">
               
              </div>'

Comment: recordando que todo lo extiendo de un base_admin.html y en el es donde tengo el avatar

Comment: En los comentarios no se puede pegar código. Edita tu pregunta y agrega ahí ese código. También agrega el código de la vista para ´usuarios/perfil/´ y para ´productos/nuevos´.

Comment: ya amigo la edite

Comment: Recuerda colocar tu código de Django, que es donde se genera tu problema. models.py, views.py, solo las partes relevantes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que la vista en la URL `producto/nuevo` no tiene el objeto `object` que supongo yo que es el usuario (no muestras esa parte del código).

Pero el objeto `user` **siempre** está en el *request* si utilizas el módulo `request` en los procesadores de contexto de tus plantillas.

Asegúrate de tener en tu configuración ese módulo `'django.template.context_processors.request'`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Y entonces podrás usar en **todas** tus plantillas esto:

```
<img src='{{ request.user.avatar.url }}' 
    alt="{{ request.user.username }}"  
    class="circle responsive-img valign profile-image">
```

Answer (score 1):

me parece que reescribise el objeto `object` y ya no es mas una instancia de modelo de usuario o bien deberia ser `user.avatar.url`

Comment: lo coloque como comentas y nada.